# How to background a nohup process using parallel ssh?

Tags: ssh

This command works:

```
parallel-ssh -i -O 'IdentityFile=control.pem' -l control  -H example.com 'nohup /home/hubot/runHubot.sh' 2>&1
```

When I log onto my server, `ps` shows me that the runHubot script is running. However, this command is not backgrounded so it doesn't return to parallel-ssh

The same command, just with a single `&` appended to `nohup` doesn't work. Why?

```
parallel-ssh -i -O 'IdentityFile=control.pem' -l control  -H example.com 'nohup /home/hubot/runHubot.sh &' 2>&1
```

This command returns to parallel-ssh, but the hubot script isn't in my `ps` output.

How can I background this process using parallel-ssh (switching to another program is not an option)?

Comment: Does the second command produce a nohup.out? If yes, what's in it?

Comment: no, not creating a nohup.out as far as i can see

Comment: But then there's no nohup.out script created for the first one either...

Comment: Does the script produce any output at all? Can you add an `echo something` to check. Have you considered using `screen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see it in `ps -elf` or `ps aux`?  `ps` may only be showing you processes with a terminal.

Comment: It's not in either, but i normally use `ps aux`